# Interdependent datepickers (Start, End) in Granite ui foundation serverside (AEM)

Tags: datepicker, aem, aem-6

I have two datepickers, where the start-datepicker shouldn't be after the end-datepicker. Also it shouldn't only be possible to set only one of them, at least should the other datepicker either go 1000 years back in time og ahead in time. So that they get a period they exist in.

In the documentation https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/datepicker/index.html I have used beforeSelector and the afterSelector, however they only give warnings and it is possible to save the dates.

I can set a validator tag, is the solution a validator javascript class?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: No. Do you have any suggestions?